# How to convert variables to an array in a pattern efficiently

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, array-algorithms

Apologies for the clumsy wording, I am struggling on how to describe this problem.

My goal is to write a function that takes in three variables and outputs a 2D array with this pattern:

```
var foo = function(x, y, z) {
    array = [
        [x + 8, y + 16, z + 35],
        [x + 6, y +  8, z + 30],
        [x + 4, y +  4, z + 20],
        [x + 2, y +  2, z + 10],
        [x    , y     , z     ],
        [x - 2, y +  2, z - 10],
        [x - 4, y +  4, z - 20],
        [x - 6, y +  8, z - 30],
        [x - 8, y + 16, z - 35]
    ]
    return array;
}
```

Obviously, this way of writing the function seems pretty inefficient.

One way I tried to solve this is with a loop. But my solution introduces three arrays and is also pretty inelegant.

```
var x_mod = [8,   6,  4,  2, 0, -2,   -4,  -6,  -8];
var y_mod = [16,  8,  4,  2, 0,  2,    4,   8,  16];
var z_mod = [35, 30, 20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30, -35];

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    array[i] = [x + x_mod[i], y + y_mod[i], z + z_mod[i]);
}
```

Is there a better way of writing this algorithm? I would also appreciate any clues as to what this kind of problem is called, or what I should study to solve it.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

This is an example of the kind of optimization I was thinking of.

The following function

```
var bar = function(x, y, z) {
    array = [
        [x + 1, y + 2, z + 3],
        [x + 2, y + 4, z + 6],
        [x + 3, y + 6, z + 9]
    ]
    return array;
}
```

could also be written in the following way:

```
var bar = function(x, y, z) {
    array = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        array[i] = [x + i, x + i*2, x + i*3];
    return array;
}
```

This is the kind of "optimization" that I wanted to apply to my original problem. Again, I apologize that I lack the vocabulary to adequately describe this problem.

Comment: The first one is the most efficient and most readable. Why need to change?

Comment: Simple math is far more efficient than indirect memory lookup. Keep it as it is.

Comment: Because the numbers follow a pattern, I thought there might be a better way than setting each array individually like this

Comment: Manu, you did not specify what exactly "better" means. Unfortunately writing code has several conflicting target functions. For example after some level performance and readability are at odds. Which is more important to you? If it is about performance, I don't think you can beat the first solution. If it is about the readability, then many depends on the meaning of those values. For example, is the person reading the code more expected to compare `x` in different rows or `x/y/z` triplet in one row? Are those values expected to be changed in any point in the future?

Comment: @SergGr I have added an example of what I was looking for to my original post. My language is sloppy because I don't really know how to describe what I'm looking for. Thank you for trying anyways :)

Comment: There's an old maxim: _Make it right before you make it faster._ Your last example is the simplest/most straightforward, and hence, most understandable. If your function is only called _once_ (i.e. during initialization), I'd use that one. You could try the multiple ways and then benchmark them. Only if one method is _significantly_ faster _and_ you _need_ the speed (as shown by the benchmark and how/when the function is called) and the function is called _many_ times, consider the faster [but less clear] version.

Comment: Another thing to consider: If you can't _measure_ it, you can't _tune_ it. So, you'll need a test rig (e.g.): `var timdif = high_precision_time(); function(); timdif = high_precision_time() - timdif;` and create some unit tests that use this to see.

Comment: "Because the numbers follow a pattern". Do they? Are you trying to ask how to describe this suposed pattern algorithmically? Perhaps start with describing it in plain English and see if your description is simpler than just enumerating them all.

Comment: So what you are asking is for a more concise way to generate the matrix, without having to hard code all the rows. So what are the _exact_ requirements? Also, the `z+35` values do not fit any pattern unlike all the other values, so there is no programmatic way to resolve this.

Comment: @ja72 Thank you, that's a good way of putting it. If `z+35` makes it impossible, I would accept `z+40` instead. When I posted this question I thought "there must be a better way to write this", but at this point I see that there's nothing that wrong with how I did it originally,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) code).

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m_2 = GenerateMatrix(2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        // result:
        // |  2.0   2.0   10.0 | + span = 2
        // |  0.0   0.0    0.0 | + 
        // | -2.0  -2.0  -10.0 |
        var m_3 = GenerateMatrix(3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        // result:
        // |  4.0   4.0   20.0 | +
        // |  2.0   2.0   10.0 | | span = 3
        // |  0.0   0.0    0.0 | +
        // | -2.0  -2.0  -10.0 |
        // | -4.0  -4.0  -20.0 |
        var m_5 = GenerateMatrix(5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        // result:
        // |  8.0  16.0   40.0 | +
        // |  6.0   8.0   30.0 | |
        // |  4.0   4.0   20.0 | | span = 5
        // |  2.0   2.0   10.0 | | 
        // |  0.0   0.0    0.0 | +
        // | -2.0  -2.0  -10.0 |
        // | -4.0  -4.0  -20.0 |
        // | -6.0  -8.0  -30.0 | 
        // | -8.0 -16.0  -40.0 | 
    }

    static double[][] GenerateMatrix(int span, double x, double y, double z)
    {
        var result = new double[2*(span-1)+1][];
        result[span-1] = new double[] { x, y, z };
        for (int i = 0; i < span-1; i++)
        {
            result[span-2-i] = new double[] { x+2*(i+1), y + (2<<i), z + 10*(i+1) };
            result[span+i] = new double[] { x-2*(i+1), y - (2<<i), z - 10*(i+1) };
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I am using the following rules (use `counter=1..span-1`). Set the rows symmetrically from the middle since they follow the same pattern with only `+` or `-` as a difference:

1. `x` values are multiples of twos, `x+2*counter` and `x-2*counter`
2. `y` values are power of twos, `pow(2,counter)=2<<counter`
3. `z` values are multiples of tens, `x+10*counter` and `x-10*counter`

Comment: While I think I'm still gonna keep my original code for readability, I'm accepting this answer because you helped me understand how I would generate my matrix, which is what I wanted at the time although now I think hard-coding the values is better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that your first definition is the best, formulas might be defined:

```
 diff =  (4 - i)
 ad = abs(diff)
 x +  diff * 2
 y +  (1 << abs(ad)) - trunc((4 - ad) / 4)
     //using bit shift to compose power of two if possible 
 z + 10 * diff - 5 * trunc(diff / 4)         
     //rounding towards zero!
```

Python check:

```
import math
for i in range(0, 9):
     diff =  (4 - i)
     ad = abs(diff)
     print(i, diff * 2, (1 << abs(ad)) - (4 - ad) // 4,  10 * diff - 5 * math.trunc(diff / 4))

0 8 16 35
1 6 8 30
2 4 4 20
3 2 2 10
4 0 0 0
5 -2 2 -10
6 -4 4 -20
7 -6 8 -30
8 -8 16 -35
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, although it might be so complicated that it hurts readability. How did you derive this formula?

Comment: I think the first column is straightforward. The second one contains powers of two, except for 4-th value, so we make correction for this case. The last one resembles the first, but we should make correction for the first and last items (with largest diff)

Comment: @Manu I would strongly vote **against** putting this into the code! This is not an improvement by any useful metric! The only case where this might be an improvement is if those numbers were received by reverse-engineering and now you want to reconstruct the formula. But I suspect this is not the case. If those numbers are produced by a formula - you should already know it. If they are not produced by a formula, putting an arbitrary formula that matches the data points is confusing the reader. It also makes code hard to change. Suppose at some point `35` should become `40`. What would you do?

Comment: @SergGr Don't worry, I agree with you completely. When I posted this question I thought "there must be a better way to write this", but at this point I see that there's nothing that wrong with how I did it originally.

Comment: @Manu, well if those numbers are always symmetric as I suspect they should be, I'd probably go with what I call "half_x_mod" approach i.e. specify `x_mod = [2,   4,  6,  8]` (and the same for `y` and `z`) and filled the matrix with something like  1. `for(i){array[x_mod.length-(i+1)] = [x - x_mod[i],...];}` 2. `array[x_mod.length] = [x,y,z]`; 3. `for(i){array[x_mod.length+(i+1)] = [x + x_mod[i],...];}` . Obviously steps #1 and #3 can be merged into one loop. This is not very fast in terms of performance but IMHO better conveys the logic which is more important in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive approach for your solution:

```
  var your_array = []
  function myFun(x, y, z, count){
        //base case
        if(count = 4)
           return;

        // head recursion
        temp = [];
        temp.push(x); temp.push(y); temp.push(z);
        your_array.push(temp);

        myFun(x-2, y/2, z-10, count+1)

        //tail recursion
        temp = []
        temp.push(x); temp.push(y); temp.push(z);
        your_array.push(temp);            
  }
```